# Different SOAP envelopes generated from same WSDL

Tags: soap, postman, soapui

I'm trying to use the generated WSDL file to create request templates for making a request to my web service. I've tried importing it with two different software, SOAP UI and Postman. What's bothering me is that the envelope is generated with different namespaces. SOAP UI generates those with `soapenv` namespace while Postman with `soap` namespace.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening and if there exists a way to `force` the usage of only one of the namespaces?

Thanks

Envelope generated from **SOAP UI**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aaa="http://abcd.fe/aaa/bbb">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aaa:update>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <placeholder>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <data>?</data>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <someOtherData>
               <aNumber>?</aNumber>
               <pNumber>?</pNumber>
            </someOtherData>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <dataCode>?</dataCode>
         </placeholder>
      </aaa:update>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Envelope generated from **Postman**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <update xmlns="http://abcd.fe/aaa/bbb">
      <placeholder>
        <data>string</data>
        <someOtherData>
          <aNumber>string</aNumber>
          <pNumber>string</pNumber>
        </someOtherData>
      </placeholder>
    </update>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Both requests are semantically equal. The namespaces are also equal. The difference in the namespace prefix should not matter since they are just aliases and XML-parsers can handle that.

Comment: I'm aware of this fact. But generating requests with different namespaces is not consistent at all. That's why I want to `force` either one of those.